# A standard for 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons in mobile browsers

Tags: android, ios, html, google-chrome

Ive noticed that mobile browsers (ie Chrome for Android and Safari for iOS )  will display 'next' and 'previous' buttons on some pages that contain forms that when clicked, change focus to a different element in the form.

I was wondering if there was a common standard that determined when these buttons appeared and  in what order the elements were focused on?
The reason I ask is that I have noticed that some pages with forms do not result in these buttons appearing, and in cases where they do appear the order in which elements are focused on is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia article about [Tabbing navigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabbing_navigation) mentions that the controls are usually focused "left to right within each row of controls" but there is also a [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) html attribute which I suppose can be used as a reference for the order.

And about the "when these buttons appear" question - I am not sure whether there is a defined standard criteria but I suppose it's related to the presence of some buttons and input fields in the page (for example search field and it's 'go' button)